# Get particular instance of a class with a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I use jQuery to get a particular instance of a class(headerGrid) within a Div(products).

I need to be able to get an instance of the class 'headerGrid' classed span which says "Get this Text". The instance is represented as the value within swap2(). My code is as follows...

```
          <table id="products">
          ...
          <tr>
          <td>
          <a onclick="swap2(1);"><img src="images/products/thumbs/image.png"/></a>
          </td>
          <td valign="top" class="product-text">
          <span class="headerGrid">Get this Text</span><br /><br />
               text
          </td>
          </tr>
          ...
          </table>
```

E.g. if *onclick="swap2(5);"* then I need to get the 5th instance of '.headerGrid'

*EDIT*

Further more I need to select the text("Get this Text") rather then the object itself. Other wise it returns object [object Object].

I also tried selecting with *.innerHTML* which returns *undefined.*

Comment: Sounds like you need [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/). Example:

```
$("#products span.headerGrid").eq(4) //Zero based index
```

With your function:

```
function swap2(n) {
    //Zero based index, subtract 1
    var theText = $("#products span.headerGrid").eq(n - 1).html();
    ...
}
```

Comment: This will only work on the first .headerGrid inside #products. If there is only one .headerGrid, you're golden. Didn't mean to downvote; reverted! Meant to just have no vote at all since I'm not sure this is the right solution yet.

Comment: Can you edit the function so I'm getting the 'Get this Text' rather then the actual object. Currently returns [object Object] and using .innerHTML returns undefined.

Comment: @JamesHill: Some people eh, I've up-voted to restore the balance

Comment: @PhilipK, I've edited the function to return the text. Simply call `.html()`

Comment: Sheesh, a misclick, a misclick! Had upvoted, meant to neutralize it but did it wrong. It's fixed (or at least my accidental downvote was).

Answer (score 4):

Using the [:nth-child selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild):

```
$('#products span.headerGrid:nth-child(5)')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `$("#products span.headerGrid:nth-child(5)")`, which will return the 5th span with class `headerGrid` in your element with ID `products`.

Function swap could look like this:

```
function swap(n){
    var element = $("#products span.headerGrid:nth-child(" + n + ")");
    //Rest of code
}
```

*Small notice: You've mentioned `DIV(products)` in your question, but your code shows `table`.*

Comment: Getting back [object Object] ??

Comment: `element` is a JQuery object. if you want to get the DOM object, use `element.get(0)`. If you want to get the text from the element, use `element.text()`

Comment: @PhilipK Use `$("#products span.headerGrid:nth-child(5)").text()`.